# What is the difference between conversion specification and format specifier in C?

Tags: c

In C I know that one uses format specifiers to indicate a data type or to specify, which data one should expect from Input. My question would be what the difference between a format specifier and conversion specification is?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-160

Answer (score 5):

Since you mention 'input', this presumably refers to the `scanf()` family of functions.  The terminology is basically the same for the `printf()` family of functions too, but they have more possible elements in a conversion specification.

A conversion specification is a complete unit such as `%*13lf`.

The (format) conversion specifier is the last letter, such as `f` in the example above.

See C11 [§7.21.6.2 The `fscanf` function](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2):

> ¶3 … Each conversion specification is introduced by the character %. After the %, the following appear in sequence:
>
> - An optional assignment-suppressing character `*`.
> - An optional decimal integer greater than zero that specifies the maximum field width (in characters).
> - An optional length modifier that specifies the size of the receiving object.
> - A conversion specifier character that specifies the type of conversion to be applied.

Comment: Interesting. Was pretty sure these are used interchangeably.

Comment: It depends whether you look at the standard or listen to and read common parlance.  In the standard, they're distinct.  In common use, the terms are mixed up.

Comment: However, in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67805947/1778275 user @Lundin concluded that _"Format specifier" appears to just be a semi-formal term_.

Comment: And user @Lundin concludes as well: _It would appear that "format specifier" and conversion specification mean the same thing_, According to this conclusion `format specifier` != `conversion specifier`.

Comment: @pmor: The C standard does not define 'format specifier'.  There is a difference between a 'conversion specification' and a 'conversion specifier'.  A conversion specifier is a single letter denoting the basic type of conversion (what will be recognized); a conversion specification is a complete multi-character unit starting at `%` and ending with the conversion specifier (consisting of at least 2 characters, therefore).  Using undefined terms (such as 'format specifier') leads to confusion because no one knows (for sure) what you're referring to.  It's why standards define terms.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the difference between 'conversion specification' and 'conversion specifier' is clear. Also @Lundin concludes (in the question linked linked above) about 7.8.1: _PRId32 as whole is supposedly a format specifier?_.

Comment: @pmor: I don't see anything about 'format specifier' in [§7.8.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.8.1) of the C11 (draft) standard — except in the section heading "Macros for format specifiers" and the footnote in the section.  That might almost be worthy of a request for a corrigendum to the standards body.  There are also two other footnotes (one under `fprintf()` and one under `fscanf()`) that reference 'format specifier'.  [Forward ¶8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Forewordp8) says that "…notes, footnotes, and examples are also for information only" — not normative.